# File Object or Path to pass for creating FileInputStream instance

Tags: java, file-io, fileinputstream

We have two constructors of the class FileInputStream as below.

```
public FileInputStream (String path) 
public FileInputStream (File file)
```

When we should go for the second approach? Even to create a File instance, we need to have the path. So is it preferable to always go for first constructor that is providing the path as an argument?

Comment: It depends what you already have. If you already have the `File`, use that, otherwise use the `String`.

Answer (score -1):

you may want to use the 1st constructor to read from a specified file, and 2nd constructor used to read from a file object ,for instance, the second approach is better than the first , you might use it with Digest Classes (e.g ZIPoutputStream and ZIPInputStream) , Moreover , Second approach indulges using same object in multiple cases

Comment: Neither is better than the other.

Comment: great if you pls elaborate a bit